# The command "docker run -e CI=true amooedwin/docker-reactv3 npm run test -- --coverage" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, npm, travis-ci

I am deploying an application in AWS using Node.JS, however Travis takes my repo from [github](https://github.com/edwinkwesi/dock-react.git) and runs it successfully but exits with 1. This is the
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkDkK.png)

I tried running `docker run -e CI=true amooedwin/docker-reactv3 npm run test -- --coverage` and also `RUN npm run build || true` in my .yaml and dockerfile, but my issue still persist

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not a CI issue, this is an issue with your code. Just try adding the below line to your App.jsx/tsx and App.test.jsx/tsx files.

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: Thanks @Chathula Sampath Perera , that worked thanks , you are awesome